# Explicit cast operator in Managed C++ for a .NET DLL

Tags: c#, .net, dll, wrapper, managed-c++

I'm writing a wrapper DLL in Managed C++ (/clr) for a native DLL with Visual Studio 2008.
This wrapper DLL will be used for .NET Programming languages, such as C#.

I have problems with my implementation of an explicit cast operator to System::String.
Casting works in a Managed C++ test program, but not in a C# test program.

This is the error I get in the C# program:

```
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'Field' to 'string'
```

Here's a simplified version of how I've done it:

```
public ref class Field
{
private:
    FieldNative* nativeObj;

public:
    Field()
    {
        nativeObj = new FieldNative();
    }

    ~Field()
    {        
        delete nativeObj; 
    }

    explicit operator System::String^(void)
    {      
        const char* value = (const char*) *nativeObj;
        return gcnew System::String(value, 0, nativeObj->size());
    }
};
```

The native object implements the casting to const char*, so this works. I can even use it in another managed C++ program. 
However, it is not working in C#.

This is how the property is exposed in the Object Browser of VS2008:

```
Field.explicit operator string ()

public explicit operator  string()
Member of Field
```

How must I implement the explicit cast operator in Managed C++ so it is usable in C# or any other .NET language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# requires operators to be static.  Write it like this to make it work:

```
    static explicit operator System::String^(Field^ obj)
    {      
        // etc..
    }
```

Comment: @Saeed - no, it is C++/CLI, the language that the OP is using.

Comment: But you write `C# requires ...` so change c# to .net, if it is.